# Windows Phone - Loading/Saving panel

Tags: controls, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I often need loading panel, which shows an indeterminate progressbar and a textblock in fullscreen mode. I do this with a Grid and just set the visibilty so visible. Instead of copy source code from page to page, I want to re-use it as a control. Is there already an existing control I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own usercontrol is the best way if you want to reuse the control. There are a lot of guides on Google, search for "custom user control silverlight" or something similar.